# Referer_tracking gem. "undefined local variable or method `has_tracking'"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I installed the referer_tracking gem, bundled, configured the ApplicationController, added 'has_tracking' to my model and restarted the server.

As soon as my model gets instantiated I get "undefined local variable or method `has_tracking'".

Using rails 4.

Any ideas? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is a mistake in readme. It should be `has_referer_tracking` instead `has_tracking` .

Comment: Thanks. Thats another 2 hours Im not getting back :-)